# The following error occurred attempting to run the project model server process (1.0.0-preview2-003131) in Visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have Visual studio 2015 with update 3 installed when i go to create project in .Net Core it shows Error dialog.

**I have only installed Visual studio 2015 with update 3**

The following error occurred attempting to run the project model server process (1.0.0-preview2-003131).

[image: Error Displayed]

I have installed SDK

[image: Installed SDK]

[image]

Comment: I think you have installed on 32bit setup on 64bit OS. Try installing Preview2-003131 64-bit version.

Comment: Say goodbye to such old bits and use VS2017 with latest .NET Core SDK.